# When to use "sbt assembly" and "sbt compile && sbt package"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I would like to know when should I use `sbt assembly` and when `sbt compile && sbt package`?

I'm coding a program in my local computer using Intellij IDEA and I'm compiling it with `sbt compile && sbt package`, then I'm going to upload it to a cluster and run it using `spark-submit`. Is this the best way? When should I use `sbt assembly`?

Comment: I don't understand why the downvote here...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I would like to know when should I use `sbt assembly` and when `sbt compile && sbt package`?

Quoting [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly)'s website (which gives `sbt assembly`):

> The goal is simple: Create a fat JAR of your project with all of its dependencies.

Any dependency in `build.sbt` (that is not marked as `Provided`) is going to be part of the final jar file that is called an uber-jar.

There are at least two reasons why you'd like to use the plugin:

1. Have all dependencies bundled together in one jar file that is much easier to deploy to production (akin to a Docker image)
2. Run your application with one Spark version, say 2.0.0, with a cluster that has `spark-submit` from Spark 1.6.0

You use `sbt compile && sbt package` to compile and package the classes of your application (which by the way does not have to use Spark whatsoever). That jar file does not include the dependencies of your application so any dependencies have to be provided in some other way (and makes deployment a bit tricker).

NB: `sbt compile && sbt package` is just a longer variant of `sbt compile package` which given that `compile` task is a dependency of `package` is just `sbt package`.

Comment: "Have all dependencies bundled together in one jar file that is much easier to deploy to production (akin to a Docker image)"

You probably don't want to put fat jars in docker image as Docker's strength is the ability to store the delta's between versions of the images. By doing fat jar, even when you changes one line of code, docker will think their entire has JAR has change. If you keep it in exploded form for Docker, it will see only the jar with the code change has changed.

Answer (score 2):

"sbt assembly" is good to use when you want to have uber jar with all dependency included. You will need assembly plugin to use "sbt assembly".

Generally, This kind of jar is good to build when you don't want to provide dependent jars separately on target machine. You can avoid dependent 3rd party jar version mismatch related issues by this kind of packaging.