# sbt package not adding dependencies

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, sbt, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to build jar using `sbt package`.

`build.sbt`:

```
name := "Simple Project"
version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
val sparkVersion = "2.3.2"
val connectorVersion = "2.3.0"
val cassandraVersion = "3.11"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "2.4.2",
  "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % connectorVersion
)
```

The `sbt package` runs successfully but does not add spark-cassandra-connector and scalaj-http to the final jar created.

Do I need to add anything?

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53744950/when-to-use-sbt-assembly-and-sbt-compile-sbt-package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the jar to contain all your dependencies, you have to use the sbt assemlbly plugin:

https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly