# sbt package runing but don't build a jar file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

** I want to build a spark streaming kafka application that will consume data from a kafka topic. But when I execute the sbt run, there is no problem, even for sbt package but no jar file creation. Can someone help me? I'm using IntelliJ IDE
**

```
this is my build.sbt

`name := "untitled4"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.10"
autoScalaLibrary := false


// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "3.0.2"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % "3.0.2"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.0.2"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.0.2
```

when I run sbt package :
this the output of sbt package.

```
 C:\Users\IdeaProjects\untitled4>sbt package
[info] welcome to sbt 1.4.7 (Oracle Corporation Java 1.8.0_281)
[info] loading global plugins from C:\.sbt\1.0\plugins
[info] loading project definition from C:\Users\IdeaProjects\untitled4\project
[info] loading settings for project untitled4 from build.sbt ...
[info] set current project to untitled4 (in build file:/C:/Users/IdeaProjects/untitled4/)
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed 27 mai 2021 11:21:41
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question isn't very clear. Are you saying that you are able to run the app from IntelliJ, but are not able to produce a jar to deploy to a server? Since the output of `sbt package` does not talk about packaginjg, I am guessing that it is already built and cached.

1. Are the jar/s not present in `/C:/Users/IdeaProjects/untitled4/` ? Is it empty?
2. Can you try running `sbt clean compile package` and check the folder again.

Also, please note that this will create multiple jar files for all the dependencies. If you need a single uber-jar for deployment, you can run `sbt assembly` [When to use "sbt assembly" and "sbt compile && sbt package"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53744950/when-to-use-sbt-assembly-and-sbt-compile-sbt-package)